# Can I get lastInsertId value after Http Client Post request?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-http-client

On laravel site making Http Post request I need to get id of the l;ast inserted ID, like:

```
$response = Http::withToken($this->token)->post(route('articles.store'), [
    'title'        => 'Item Title lorem',
    'text'         => 'Item Text lorem',
    'text_shortly' => 'Item Text shortly lorem',
    'published'    => true,
]);

$lastItemId = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId(); // this value is 0
```

New value is added and I see sql insert statement in sql logs, but $lastItemId is zero...

Can I to get this value somehow ?

```
"laravel/framework": "^9.19",
"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This: `DB::getPdo()` is wrong, the lastInsertId() is already on the DB object

Comment: Why are you doing a POST request to your own site? That is generally bad practice. Usually you'd extract the controller code to a separate utility library and call that from both the controller and this code, that way you can control what to return. Sidenote: Because you are doing this your site is creating a new database connection and the last insert ID is on that connection not the one that is making the request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can select id from the last row

```
Article::select('id')->latest();
```

Comment: I don't know why this is accepted. ***In case two data are written on the database, you get the wrong id of it, Not what you wrote.*** anyway, okay...

Comment: this code always get you the last id of table

Comment: and he dont want the inserted row id. he jus want to get last records id

Answer (score 2):

To get `lastInsertId`, you need some altering to be done.

---

**In the Store function**

```
$article = Article::create([
    'title' => $request->input('title'),
    # your fields
]);

return response()->json(['id' => $article->id]);  # importent part
```

**In the HTTP Client**

```
$lastItemId = $response->json()['id'];
```